# Perforce line-by-line merge

Tags: perforce

I am trying to get familiar with P4 trying to resolve a merge conflict. Let's suppose User1 and User2 got their development stream from mainline and they are both working on the same file: User1 write "string 1" first and submit changes and copied to main. User2 get the new file and add a new string "another string". User2 do not submit. User1 change "string 1 " into "string 2" and submit changes again.

User2 try to submit change but cannot copy to main because first line conflicted. So trying to merge-down with 3-way merge tool do not let User2 what to select line-by-line. Is that the normal behavior? The only solution seems to accept User2 solution and manually edit first line to change "1" into "2". I am not sure why it is not possible as User2 still got the old "string 1" which has nothing to do with the new line being added..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "another string" got added immediately after "string 1", here's what the conflict resolution looks like (at the command line):

```
>>>> ORIGINAL //depot/merge/same_file.txt#2
string 1
==== THEIRS //depot/merge/same_file.txt#3
string 2
==== YOURS //Samwise-dvcs-1509687817/merge/same_file.txt
string 1
another string
<<<<
```

User 1's change is "THEIRS", and User 2 (the one who's doing the merge) is "YOURS".  Since the changes are right next to each other, they're grouped into a single "chunk" -- "string 1" no longer exists in the "THEIRS" leg, so it's not obvious to the merge algorithm where "string 2" would go relative to "another string".

Comment: You mean it might be the case that User2 want to change first line too but it's not possible to make assumptions if that line is a new one or previous one because the original first line doesn't exists anymore? That make sense but in that case P4 is assuming it's always the first case. For me there are 2 outstanding changes, first line and second line, not necessarily they must be grouped together but maybe P4 implement this way. SVN allow you to specify line by line what to merge. If changes involves several consecutive lines then you have to edit all lines.

Comment: Perforce's default merge algorithm errs on the side of grouping things together into conflicts, since that's generally the "safe" option.  You can set `P4MERGE` if you prefer to use a third-party merge algorithm that's more daring.  :)